# Как считать посимвольно данные до пробела?

Tags: c++

Как считывать посимвольно данные до пробела с консоли или файла? `cin >>`не помогает, игнорирует пробелы.

Comment: Откуда считывать? Из файла? С клавиатуры? Или еще откуда?

Comment: @gecube, видимо проблема чтения cin >> c из stdin.

Кстати, а кому вопрос не понравился (минуснул-то кто?) попробуйте:


    while (cin.good()) {
      char c; 
      cin >> c;
      //c = cin.get();  а так работает
      if (c == ' ') {
        cout << "space\n";
        break;
      }
      if (cin.good())
        cout << "c=" << c << '\n';
    }

Comment: Ну, я не минусовал точно - просто были непонятки чего хотел автор.

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Консоль. Считывание нажатой клавиши](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/415921/%d0%9a%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c-%d0%a1%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%88%d0%b8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Видимо у Вас проблема с чтением из **`std::cin`**

Я вообще предпочитаю весь ввод-вывод делать на чистом Си, но если интересует C++ и читать надо именно из `cin`, а не из ifstream, то по моему простейшим решением будет использование
**`cin.read`**.

Что-то вроде

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main ()
{
  char c = 0;
  int rc = 0;

  while (cin.read(&c,1)) {
    if (c == ' ')
      break;
    cout <<  "get[" << c <<"] ";
  }

  if (cin.good())
    cout << "space\n";
  else if (cin.eof())
    cout << "EOF\n";
  else {
    rc = 1;
    cout << "Err\n";
  }

  return rc;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  string s;

    cin >> s;

    for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++){
        cout << "[" << s[i] << "]" << endl;
    }
}
```

---

```
djskfjsdj j ksdjfkjsd djsfkjsdlkfjsd sdjfsdkljf
[d]
[j]
[s]
[k]
[f]
[j]
[s]
[d]
[j]
Для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу . . .
```

Answer (score 0):

`fscanf` считывает до пробела, очень удобно для `char *`.
Но это в том случае, если ты хочешь считывать из файла до пробела потоком данных, не посимвольно.