# Консоль. Считывание нажатой клавиши

Tags: c++, c

Нужно, чтобы после нажатия на кнопку программа работала дальше. Чтобы после этой кнопки не приходилось еще жать <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Как я понял, этим занимается `getchar()`, но у меня он не работает, приходится жать <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Код для Windows:

```
while (z != ' ') {
    cout<< "Нажмите SPACE " << endl;
    z = getchar();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

На **Windows** можно использовать ***getch()*** вместе с заголовочным файлом ***conio.h***.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>


int main() {
   int z
   while (z != ' ') {
      cout<< "Нажмите SPACE " << endl;
      z = getch();
   }
}
```

На ***nix-OS** есть ***curses.h*** (***ncurses.h***), там также имеется функция ***getch()***. Однако при использовании данной функции вы остаетесь привязаны к **curses**, поэтому желательно использовать следующую конструкцию:

```
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int getch( ) {
   struct termios oldt,
   newt;
   int ch;
   tcgetattr( STDIN_FILENO, &oldt );
   newt = oldt;
   newt.c_lflag &= ~( ICANON | ECHO );
   tcsetattr( STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &newt );
   ch = getchar();
   tcsetattr( STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &oldt );
   return ch;
}
```

Также на **Windows** можно использовать **PDCurses** для создания мультиплатформенных консольных приложений, он почти полностью совместим с **ncurses**.

Comment: Нужно ли отключать  в `getch()` ECHO или нет это вообще-то не очевидно. И учтите, что эти вызовы tcgetattr/tcsetattr для чтения каждого символа не слишком рациональны. Т.е. если используете для ввода в цикле только  getch(), то разумней переводить поток в нужный режим перед и после цикла (серии getch()), а не при каждом его вызове.

Answer (score 1):

Переносимым образом — [никак](http://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/input-output#kbhit).

C++ рассчитан на то, что стандартные потоки могут быть перенаправлены, поэтому ввод буферизуется, и доступа напрямую к клавиатуре нет.

Тем не менее, есть способы, основанные на системно-зависимых библиотеках.

Например, под Windows-системами вы можете воспользоваться WinAPI-функциями [`ReadConsoleInput`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684961%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)/[`GetNumberOfConsoleInputEvents`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683207%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Под Linux-системами вам поможет библиотека curses/[ncurses](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/).

На старых DOS-системах есть `getch` в `conio.h`.

Учтите, что если вы пользуетесь низкоуровневым вводом/выводом, нормальный потоковый ввод-вывод скорее всего не будет функционировать нормально. Так что или `cin`/`cout`, или низкоуровневые трюки, иначе сюрпризов не избежать.

Comment: без winapi нельзя какой-нибудь  обычной виндовой библиотекой сделать?

Comment: WinAPI и есть как бы виндовая библиотека. Может быть, к ней есть обёртки, конечно.

Comment: getch работает так как надо, но есть библиотеки поновее, без .h ? cconio, как оказалось, нет

Comment: @neko69: Нет, `conio.h` в любом случае устарела, так что современного варианта не будет :-( Ну и учтите ещё раз замечание в конце ответа.

Comment: а низкоуровневые трюки это трюки с асмом уже?

Comment: @neko69: Это всё, что не пользуется cin/cout внутри. В частности, conio.h.