# getch() - ожидание нажатия клавиши в C++

Tags: c++, c, ncurses, клавиатура

Обычно `getch()` ждет до того, как пользователь нажмет клавишу, и если он не нажмет клавишу, функция не завершится никогда.

Как сделать ожидание нажатия в, скажем, полсекунды, после чего функция завершается, возвращая, к примеру, `0x00`?

Comment: связанный вопрос [Консоль. Считывание нажатой клавиши](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/415921/23044)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по `getch`, ты пишешь в чём-то старом и тебе доступна `kbhit` - используй её для проверки, есть ли нажатая клавиша.

Если надо современное, то используй winapi-функцию `PeekConsoleInput`.

Comment: Почему в старом? NCurses живет и здравствует) А вообще, спасибо за совет)

Comment: @velikiyv4, потому что функции из `conio.h` наполовину почистили, а оставшаяся часть местами глючит. По крайней мере, я в VS именно с `getch` с проблемами сталкивался.

Answer (score 0):

Для организации задержки можно использовать  while(!kbhit()) {...}
А вместо просто getch() использовать лучше вариант _getch()

Comment: Почему `_getch` лучше? о_О